# distinguish classes that inherited App with get_running_app()

Tags: python, kivy

I got two classes that have two methods that I want to be able to access from different classes, so I inherited from App in both classes to use get_running_app with kivy properties (hope you understand what I'm saying). Now I have a problem because when I try calling App.get_running_app().method(), it only looks for the method in the first class, but the method is in the second class.  I know that inheriting from App in two classes isn't really good but that was at the time the easiest way because I didn't have to call get_running_app for both classes. I had like the main class (where the def build is) and one just for main screen and I needed to call a method in main screen class. Now I have that method and the method in the main class.

So my question is, is there any way of distinguishing two classes with get_running_app()? Or could you give me some tips on how to solve this problem in different way if you have some idea?

Here is the code like you asked, just forget what this code does, I simplified it like this just to show the core problem and the error it doesn't matter what does.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class GameWidget(Screen, App):
    num = NumericProperty(0)
    change_value = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num = 0
        self.button = Button(text="go back", size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'x': 0.4, 'y':0.4},
                             on_press=lambda x: self.go_main_screen())
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.label = Label(text=str(self.num), size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'x':0.2, 'y':0.2})
        self.add_widget(self.label)

    def change_value(self):
        self.num += 1
        self.label.text = str(self.num)

    def go_main_screen(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = 'main'



class Main_screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main_screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.button = Button(text='click me', size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.4},
                             on_release=lambda x: self.call_methods())
        self.button2 = Button(text='go to next screen', size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'x':0.4, 'y':0.6},
                              on_release=lambda x: self.ch_screen())
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.add_widget(self.button2)


    def ch_screen(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.manager.current = 'game'
    def call_methods(self):
        App.get_running_app().change_value()
        App.get_running_app().print_some_stuff()



class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    print_some_stuff = ObjectProperty(None)
    def build(self):
        sm = Manager()
        sm.add_widget(Main_screen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(GameWidget(name='game'))
        return sm

    def print_some_stuff(self):
        print('you clicked')


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: It sounds like what you've done would be a weird/bad code structure even if it worked, which it doesn't. I suggest posting a minimal runnable example demonstrating your problem, with a clear explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @inclement of course!

Comment: @inclement here I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App.get_running_app()` method will always return the same object, which should be the currently running `App`. Since you can only have one running `App`, that should always be the `MyApp` instance in your code. However, I believe you have uncovered a bug in the `App` code, because `App.get_running_app()` actually returns the last created `App`, not the currently running `App`. So, in your code, it will always return the `GameWidget` instance. That bug will not affect a correctly structured code.

The following problems/solutions appear in your code:

- You should not have more than one `App` class in your `App`. Change:

  class GameWidget(Screen, App):

  to:

  class GameWidget(Screen):
- You can access `Screens` using the `get_screen()` method of the `ScreenManager`, which is your `App` root. So you can chaange:

  App.get_running_app().change_value()

  to:

  App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('game').change_value()